# NodeJS app recognize cluster IP but not communicate with the pod himself

Tags: mysql, node.js, kubernetes, service

I have Nodejs application running in K8S ( Minikube running in hyperv) , the application connecting to DB.

This DB is running also in k8S as MySQL.

Nodejs DB Connection

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "mysql" ,//work only if you get the ip of the mysql running pod ! need to exec the pod the get the ip
    user:'root',
    password:'root',
    database:'crud'
});
connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected..!');
    }
});

module.exports = connection;
```

as you can see I use `"host: "mysql"`
and the nodejs logs show me that the NodeJs application recognize what it "mysql" dns name becuse i have clusterIP service for it

```
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.102.140.203',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
```

this IP address (10.102.140.203) that I see in the log is the CluserIP address of the MySQL service

```
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
app           ClusterIP   10.111.211.9     <none>        3000/TCP         62m
appnodeport   NodePort    10.99.179.176    <none>        3000:30958/TCP   62m
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          71m
mysql         ClusterIP   10.102.140.203   <none>        3306/TCP         62m
mysqlnode     NodePort    10.106.157.92    <none>        3306:31186/TCP   57m
```

BUT if I enter the pod himself of the SQL and get the IP address , 172.x.x.x and enter it to the NodeJS DB connection

```
host: "172.x.x.x.x" 
user:'root',
password:'root',
database:'crud'
```

the NodeJS application connected fine , but i dont want to do it in this way becuse the ip of the pod himself changes sometimes if the pod is restarting , i want to use service name or something that is not changes.

**NodeJS Deployment Yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.24.0 (7c629530)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: app
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: app
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\kompose.exe convert
        kompose.version: 1.24.0 (7c629530)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: xxx/app:6
          name: employees-app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources: {}
      hostname: app
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

NodeJS Service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.24.0 (7c629530)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: app
  name: app
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "3000"
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: app
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**MySQL deployment yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "root"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: '/var/lib/mysql'
          name: mysql-persistent-storage
      hostname: mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

mySQL service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\kompose.exe convert
    kompose.version: 1.24.0 (7c629530)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "3306"
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: mysql
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: If you want something that will not change, you definitely need to use DNS. It says you can not get connected by DNS because the connection was refused, this could be becase of a port block, firewall or some kind of denied permission. My suggestion for you is to open `MySQL Workbench, MySQL-Front` or another MySQL software and try to connect from your computer to the MySQL K8S using the IP `10.102.140.203`. The software will give you the exactly error message and you can debug it, once you connect in the software you come back to nodejs and it will probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution , just used "Endpoint" the Endpoint its the IP addr of the running pod himself  , so i used the name of it :)

Answer (score 0):

It will also work if while defining your mysql-service.yaml, you use ClusterIP: none. That will expose the endpoint as endpoint rather than as VirtualIP.